# Maintain centre coordinate while pinching MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

If you pinch to zoom in/out in Apple's Maps application while tracking the device's location, the "pan" component of the pinch gesture is ignored and the blue location indicator remains fixed in the centre of the screen. This is not the case when using a plain `MKMapView`.

Assuming I already have the user's location, how could I achieve this effect? I've tried resetting the centre coordinate in the delegate's `regionDid/WillChangeAnimated:` methods but they're only called at the start and end of the gesture. I also tried adding a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` subclass that resets the centre coordinate when the touches move, but this resulted in rendering glitches.

---

**Edit:** For those who are interested, the following works for me.

```
// CenterGestureRecognizer.h
@interface CenterGestureRecognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer

- (id)initWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView;

@end
```

```
// CenterGestureRecognizer.m
@interface CenterGestureRecognizer ()

- (void)handlePinchGesture;

@property (nonatomic, assign) MKMapView *mapView;

@end

@implementation CenterGestureRecognizer

- (id)initWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView {
  if (mapView == nil) {
    [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"mapView cannot be nil."];
  }

  if ((self = [super initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture)])) {
    self.mapView = mapView;
  }

  return self;
}

- (BOOL)canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  return NO;
}

- (BOOL)canPreventGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  return NO;
}

- (void)handlePinchGesture {
  CLLocation *location = self.mapView.userLocation.location;
  if (location != nil) {
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:location.coordinate];
  }
}

@synthesize mapView;

@end
```

Then simply add it to your `MKMapView`:

```
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:[[[CenterGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the user pinches the screen on the actual device (as opposed to the simulator), it causes both a pan *and* a pinch gesture – the pinch contains the "zoom" element of the motion, and the pan contains the vertical and horizontal change. You need to be intercepting and blocking the pan, and that means using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Set `scrollEnabled` to `NO`, then add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to reset the center coordinate. The combination will block both single-finger panning and the pan component of a pinch.

---

**Edit** to add more details, and after seeing your code: `touchesMoved:withEvent` is called after the pan has already begun, so if you change the MKMapView's center there, you'll get the herky-jerky rendering problems you've described. What you really need is to create a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with a target-action, like so:

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didRecognizePan)] autorelease];
    pan.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

...and then add a `didRecognizePan` method to your controller, and do your center-resetting there.

Comment: This resulted in the same rendering problems as mentioned above: the map view's centre alternates frequently between the user's location and where it would be had the gesture recognisers run their course.

Perhaps I've misunderstood your answer? I've posted the implementation of my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` subclass here: http://pastie.org/1934011

Comment: That did the trick! I'm glad the solution was so simple. Thanks, Scott.

Comment: What if we want to allow user single finger panning as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but have you tried setting `scrollEnabled` to `NO` at the start of `regionWillChangeAnimated:`?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. If I set it to `NO` at the start (outside of the delegate methods), single finger panning is disabled but the "pan" components of pinch gestures are still used.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as well.  At the start of regionWillChangeAnimated: save the current map region, then continuously update the region via an NSTimer using self.myMapView.region=theSavedRegion or similar.  Then invalidate the timer when regionDidChangeAnimated: is called.

However, you might have an issue where the region update by the NSTimer causes regionWillChangeAnimated to be called again.

Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: I suspect that this will result in the same rendering glitches as mentioned in the question; it's effectively doing the same thing, just with a timer rather than a `UIGestureRecognizer`. I'll investigate and report back if I have any success.

Comment: I played around a bit with trying to intercept pan gestures but that didn't seem to work. Good luck, can't wait to hear what the solution is!